# Why is the filter aggregation necessary?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

While using elasticsearch (5.3.0) we ran into an out of memory problem on a query involving a few nested aggregations.

We found empirically that the problem was that the aggregations were computed on the full index rather than taking into account the conditions specified in the `query` block. We later managed to run the query moving those conditions into a `filter` aggregation (see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)) that wrapped all our original aggs.

Why is there a separate syntax for this? Wouldn't it be better if elasticsearch simply took into account all query conditions while populating buckets?

What are the risks and/or limitations if I choose to wrap all my aggregation queries in a `filter` query in this way? Is there any difference in logic?

**NOTE:** In our application we do not care about document scoring at all. All conditions have the only purpose of filtering the documents, not sorting them. We do filter the buckets either on document count or on aggregation metrics.

**EDIT:** some people asked for the queries and here they are in case they help clarifying the situation. Please do note that the question is general and *not* specific for this particular case.

```
{
  "query": {
    // we did try a filtering rather than a query with the same results
    "term": {
      "urlpath": "some_url_path.html"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_1": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "sessions_number": "desc"
        },
        "field": "urlpath"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sessions_number": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "session"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and after:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "agg_0": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "urlpath": "some_url_path.html"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_1": {
          "terms": {
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "sessions_number": "desc"
            },
            "field": "urlpath"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sessions_number": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "session"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT2:** I tried using a filter query, as suggested by @Lusid below, but had the same issue.

**NOTE2:** we do not incur in the problem if we remove the `order` clause and this is also true with a filter rather than a query. This is most surprising to us since there *should* be only one bucket, making any ordering trivial. This is what lead me to believe that the filtering was not taking place before the bucketing and for this reason I tried to wrap everything in a filtering aggregation.

Comment: Can you post your initial query and the modified one?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are not actually **filtering** the data, you are **querying** the data. This only effects the scoring process for results of the search, not filtering of aggregations.

Even though the most recent versions of ElasticSearch have combined the query/filter syntax, it is still important to understand the difference between the two. According to the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

> A query clause used in query context answers the question “How well
>   does this document match this query clause?” Besides deciding whether
>   or not the document matches, the query clause also calculates a _score
>   representing how well the document matches, relative to other
>   documents.
>
> In filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this
>   document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or
>   No — no scores are calculated. Filter context is mostly used for
>   filtering structured data, e.g.

A better way to structure your first query would be by wrapping the filter in **query.bool** or **query.constant_score** like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "urlpath": "some_url_path.html"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_1": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "sessions_number": "desc"
        },
        "field": "urlpath"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sessions_number": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "session"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More information on these two options here:

Constant Score Query:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Bool Query (Filter Section):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Of course, the advantage to having both of these options is that you can apply an overall filter for the entire search, but then further filter aggregations.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** I was mostly addressing the reasoning behind the filter not functioning the way you were expecting in the aggregate due to using it in the query. As for the memory issue, are you sure you aren't triggering a combinatorial explosion here? You could try adding a collect_mode of breadth_first to the top level aggregate? More information on combinatorial explosions here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_preventing_combinatorial_explosions.html

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "urlpath": "some_url_path.html"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_1": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "sessions_number": "desc"
        },
        "field": "urlpath",
        "collect_mode": "breadth_first"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sessions_number": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "session"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer; I tried your variant right away but unfortunately I got the same results (out of memory). I will add a few more details as an edit in the question shortly.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't addressing the memory issue. I've updated my answer to propose a possible cause and solution to the memory issue (although, without seeing your data, I can't be sure).

Answer (score 1):

Filtering an aggregation is also necessary if you have nested documents. This allows to aggregate on specific sub-document instead of aggregate on all items.